# What's the limit of this sequence?

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots + 1 \bigg)$

My attempt:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots + 1 \bigg)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{n^3}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n^3}}+\cdots + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}} \bigg)=0+\cdots+0=0$

Comment: Your $n^2$s should be $n^3$s. In any case, you distributed the limit over the sum which is not, in general, valid.

Comment: Apply Lema STOLZ-CESARO.

Comment: Your right hand side "$\large 0 + 0 + \cdots$" is wrong.

Comment: Your right hand side "$\large 0 + 0 + \cdots$" is wrong. It's like the "proof" $\displaystyle{\large 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\underbrace{{1 \over n} + {1 \over n} + \cdots + {1 \over n}\,}_{n\ \mbox{times}\,}\right) = 0}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $f(x) := \sqrt{x}$. Then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right) \dfrac1{n} = \int_0^1 f(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

$$
\int_{0}^{n}x^{1/2}\,\dd x
<
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}k\,}
<
\int_{1}^{n + 1}x^{1/2}\,\dd x
\quad\imp\quad
{2 \over 3}\,n^{3/2}
<
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}k\,}
<
{2 \over 3}\bracks{\pars{n + 1}^{3/2} - 1}
$$

$$
{2 \over 3}\quad
<\quad
{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}k \over n\,}\quad
<\quad
{2 \over 3}\bracks{\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}^{3/2} - {1 \over n^{3/2}}}
$$

$$
\vphantom{\Huge A}
$$

$${\large%
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\pars{{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}k \over n\,}\,\,}
=
{2 \over 3}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

By that same argument, the limit of $$\frac1n(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{\text{$n$ summands}})$$ is zero. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your limit seems to be 2/3 but I do not know how to prove it except using Njguliyev's hint